# Databases application-level logical removal - when to use

Tags: database, persistence

I've read that the **remove operation is infrequently used**, and that it common fact when the data are never removed from the database. In return, data are **marked as outdated**, so called '**application-level logical removal**'.

*My questions are:*

1. In which cases it is better/preferable?
2. Why not just remove? It seems to be easier.
3. Do this statement refers to all databases or only t osome specific (for example,only to relational)